# Are there any benefits to keeping a tail while bipedal?

Tags: anatomy

I'm making a species of completely bipedal monkeys* (Not apes), and is there any evolutionary reason for them to keep their prehensile tails instead of being rid of them?

*The monkeys are much smaller than humans, standing at about 2~4 feet tall, with tails around the same length as their body, give or take.

[image: A space monkey!]

Possible reasons I've come up with:

- Balance in running
- Extra manipulating limb
- Fat storage
- Temperature regulation (If the tail becomes hairless, like rats)

But I don't know how well these actually work.

Comment: Where do they usually hang out?

Comment: @user6760 They're space monkeys, so... Usually urban environments and space stations. I imagine there are lots of places for them to climb as a way of navigating their cities though.

Comment: You've not mentioned religious/cultural preference, are you looking at purely *practical* reasons for it? They could each work, it rather depends on their physical proportions. Can you tell us about their general limb-length, stature etc., or give us a sketch to work from?

Comment: When you say "...is there any reason..." are you meaning an evolutionary reason or a choice regarding amputation surgery (like a human getting their appendix removed)?  Initially I was reading it as the former, but with your comment added we need more info, especially what is the gravity in their space stations and cities.  If you do mean evolutionary reasons, then we need to know how they got to the cities-and-space-stations level.

Comment: @Escapeddentalpatient. Sketch added. I had not thought about cultural reasons, but I would still prefer to keep the focus on practical reasons.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 Evolutionary reasons. They copy a lot of things from human history, especially since they are from Earth without really any intended changes other than monkeys lucked out over apes. The gravity varies widely because they do not have artificial gravity. These monkeys will just have to deal with the differing gravities of planets and the cold vacuum of space.

Comment: There will be benefits in some environments/situations/behaviours and disadvantages in others.  Without writing the entire evolution of this species for you, we can't answer this.  It may be better to come at this from the other direction - decide whether you want the monkey-descendants to have tails or not and ask how it can be justified either way (although even that may be considered too subjective).  The sketch and info (especially the oversized, wide-set eyes) tell us that their evolutionary path is very different to that of humans.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 Clearly they were bio engineered for a giggle by a bunch alternate world hopping tourist anime fans from Japan, hence the big eyes .. that was centuries ago and written history only developed after the tourists went home of course so they've forgotten that.

Comment: Kangaroos are bipedal but use their tail a lot. But that is a completely different way of moving about.

Comment: for a spacefaring species absolutely, the more grasping limbs the better for zero G.

Comment: Look at kangaroos they basically use it as a 3. Leg.

Comment: VTC:Not About Worldbuilding per the Help Center. The [help/dont-ask] states that providing your own answers and asking for more is prohibited. What you just told us is that you have answers but, for some reason, either don't like them or don't trust them. While a good frame challenge would be that tails cause more problems for bipedals than they solve (they reduce agility, for one) the truth is any of your proposed answers would work. Pick one and move on.

Answer (score 1):

Working with your hands and feet free- so basically a climbing assistance possibly augmented with a rope.

Steering of vehicles, as its directly on an instinctual level connected with the balancing organ. Could be a micro-thruster-jetpack kept level.

It really depends upon the dexterity the tail has. A elephant trunk can do delicate procedures a apes tail can clench and unclench around things..

Comment: By definition, apes don't have tails.

Answer (score 1):

For reasons to do with testosterone and endocrine responses and other genetics-adjacent chemistry magic, healthy males who have a good diet have longer, darker tails. Females like this because anything that signifies health and a good diet signifies all the traits that will make babies strong and a male a good provider for the tribe. Females therefore usually won't let males have sex unless their tails are long and dark.

The genes that keep male tails long keep female tails long-ish, although they are not quite as long. Medium-sized blonde tails are sexy on ladies. But what matters, since females do most of the selecting, is that every girl's crazy 'bout a long-and-dark-tailed man.

The tails aren't especially harmful, and they're not especially helpful, either. But they do cost calories to make and maintain. But since the main point of the tail is as a signifier of access to a good diet, this doesn't count as a mechanism for selecting against the tails, as long as the monkeys don't end up spending many generations struggling with a crisis of insufficient calories.